# Laravel 4.2 - Environment detection - homestead.yaml vs. start.php

Tags: laravel, environment, homestead

Homestead version: 2.0.7

Laravel version: 4.2.16

I'm just starting to learn Laravel, and I'm confused about the difference between environment configurations with start.php and homestead.yaml.  Here's what I have:

start.php:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

   'local' => array('josh-linux'),
   'production' => array('homestead')

));
```

homestead.yaml:

```
variables:
- key: APP_ENV
  value: testing123
```

If I run 'php artisan env' in the terminal it says 'local', and if I ssh into my homestead box and run 'php artisan env' it says 'production', which is what I'd expect.  (I just threw 'production' in there to test the value returned).

If I throw `<?php var_dump(getenv('APP_ENV')) ?>` in hello.php and refresh the page, it displays 'testing123', which was the setting for APP_ENV in homestead.yaml.

I'm just confused with knowing when each one is used?  What is the purpose of the APP_ENV value if environment detection is being done in the start.php file, and vice versa?  Also, should I have 'local' look for both my machine name and the homestead box name?  Because I'm also not sure of the point of detecting the 'homestead' environment.  (This is my first experience with VM's so I'm sure there's something I'm missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get the environment in your laravel app should be

```php
$environment = app()->environment();
```

or via the helper facade

```php
$environment = App::environment();
```

This ensures that you don't get different results.

---

If you like to use the `homestead.yaml` environment variable instead of the standard `start.php` of laravel 4 you can change it to this in your `start.php`:

```php
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'production';
});
```

Now it looks for the `APP_ENV` variable and if not found it defaults to `production`.

The `php artisan env` command should then output the same as `App::environment();`

> #### Note
>
> If you switch between laravel 4.2 and 5.0 make sure that you have in mind that the environment technique changed a little. See here for mor information:
>
> Laravel 4.2: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration
> Laravel 5.0: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration