# laravel 4.2 environment setup on ubuntu

Tags: php, database, laravel, ubuntu, environment

I followed the other post in stackoverflow.  I had pretty much the same question but the problem is that his answer didn't solve my problem.

The post I tried is
[Laravel 4.2 - Environment detection - homestead.yaml vs. start.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222045/laravel-4-2-environment-detection-homestead-yaml-vs-start-php)

I tried the answer in that post but I get errors like

```
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function environment() on null in /home/vagrant/Code/tickets/bootstrap/start.php on line 34
```

I checked using `php artisan env` it just says production but when I use the code / method from the post above and I used `php artisan env` in terminal I will get the error instead of saying production.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance for any help